# If $P(A)=.44, P(B)=.27,$ and $P(A\text{ or }B)=.6,$ are $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive events? Why or why not?

Tags: probability

If $P(A)=.44, P(B)=.27,$ and $P(A\text{ or }B)=.6,$ are $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive events? Why or why not?

Comment: For any events, a and b, p(a or b)= p(a)+ p(b)- p(a and b).  Two events are called "mutually exclusive" if p(a and b)= 0.  Is 0.6= 0.44+ 0.27?

Comment: What do YOU think and why?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of mutually exclusive is that the intersection (aka $P\ (A\text{ and }B)$) equals zero. To find $P(A\text{ and }B),$ we compute $P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ or }B)=0.44+0.27-0.6=0.11,$ which is clearly greater than zero. This means that A and B are not mutually exclusive.

(And by the way, if this is homework, you should at least try something and then post the question *along with your work*; it's much better to learn that way, and plus homework is usually discouraged here)

Comment: i thought they were not mutually exclusive however i mistakenly believed i was supposed to add 0.6 not subtract it.T hank you i was incorrect.